# Pointers and addresses?

Tags: c, pointers

I entered the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int *ptr, x, y;
    ptr = &x;
    y = x;

    printf("This is the value on location of x: %p\n", *ptr);
    printf("This is the address of x: %p\n", &x);
    printf("The value of x is *ptr is: %i %x\n", *ptr);
    printf("This is the address of ptr: %p\n", &ptr);
    printf("The value of y is: %i\n", y);
    printf("The address of y is %p\n", &y);

    return 0;
}
```

And the console shows the following:

> This is the address of x: 000004F
>   This is the address of x: 0028FF18
>   The value of x is *ptr is: 79  28ff94
>   This is the address of ptr: 0028FF1C
>   The value of y is 0028FF14

I can understand all the printf result, but except the 3rd line for the 2nd value `28ff94`?
I know the 1st value `%d79` is `%x000004F` for `*ptr = x`. 
I expressly did not specify 2nd value, is empty. But now I wonder where the hex value `28ff94` comes from?

Comment: Did you forget to assign value to `x` ?

Comment: No. Everything is written intentionally. I want to know why 28ff94 would represent?

Comment: Fix your output, there is no way your program could produce this output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing an uninitialized variable results in undefined behaviour.  It may be that the program simply printed whatever garbage value was previously in that space in memory.

Since C was meant to be a clean and efficient language, it doesn't automatically fill in a value, it simply allocates an amount of memory.  This section of memory retains its previous value until you initialize it as something else.

Comment: Thanks Magister!. Is the assigned location also arbitrary? random? or follows certain rules?

Comment: @viktorkh: That's up to the specific implementation, but there are usually well-defined rules for setting aside storage.  Google "stack frame" to see the typical methods.

Comment: Indeed it is very implementation specific but I would point you towards Googling "Addressing Modes" as this is a rather broad topic that specifically deals with how a memory address is determined, it is quite interesting.